# K-approximation algorithms

Tags: graphs, approximation

I am attempting to understand exactly how the terminology for k-approximation algorithms work, from when k is known and determining what k is.

If we assume that a vertex cover in a graph G is of size 7 and that there is a 3-approximation algorithm for finding the minimum vertex cover. Does that mean the algorithm could return values between 7 and 21 inclusive?

If the maximum independent set in a graph is of size 12 and an algorithm returns for a complement graph a clique of size 6 in the worst case. Would that algorithm be a 2-approximation or a .5-approximation?

Comment: If an algorithm is $k$-approximation for an NP-hard **maximization problem** than it is true that $v^\star/k\leq v\leq v^\star$ for any instance of the problem, where $v^\star$ is the optimal value and $v$ is the value returned by the algorithm and $k\geq1$. Alternatively, we can define it as $k\cdot v^\star\leq v\leq v^\star$ but with $k\leq1$.